# Can you actually prove if the null hypothesis is true or a type II error has occurred?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

Can you actually prove if the null hypothesis is true or a type II error has occurred?

I'm new to statistics (sorry in advance!)

Comment: Yes…if you knew the answer before you ran the hypothesis test. That sounds ridiculous, but it can be important to simulation studies.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. The are indistinguishable and this is one of the key challenges in statistics. An alternative comparison can be made between finding a significant result (because H0 is false) vs a type 1 error. We can attempt to control these error rates but it is always a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

No, but non rejection makes you take a decision. So it acts as if you proved the null in practical sense

Comment: I kind of follow what you mean, but this is such confusing phrasing for a newcomer to statistics.